# Correct way to register custom post type from external php file?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, hooks

I have a class file and I have separated out my custom post types into their own files in a sub-folder for neatness, readability, etc.

I want to init the CPT now in my plugin's `index.php` class. My class is initialised on the `plugins_loaded` action and in my construct I have the following:

```
public function __construct() {
    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this,'init_admin_scripts'));
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this,'init_frontend_scripts'));
}
```

The above actions refer to functions that are in the `index.php` file itself. My CPTs are in a subfolder called `cpt`. What is the correct way to add the action for the functions in a subfolder?

Comment: Why not use `include` or `require` before calling those functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an action doesn't do anything except putting the callback function in the queue of the corresponding hook. It doesn't check if the function exists, let alone load a file where the function is resident.

Only when the corresponding hook is fired PHP looks for the function. If it is not loaded by then it simply throws an error:

> **Warning**:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a
>   valid callback, function 'yada_yada' not found or invalid function
>   name in **/../wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php** on line **286**

So, you are yourself responsible for loading the file where the function resides using `include` or `require` **before** the `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook is fired. Refer to the [hook order list](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_an_Admin_Page_Request) to check if you're hooking timely. If you're hooking everything into `plugins_loaded` you should be fine.